# Selective CSS Aggregation for fast D7 development performance

Tags: theming, performance, css-js-aggregation

On D6, we had the [this module](http://drupal.org/project/ie_css_optimizer). Depite the module's name, it has an *hidden* extra feature to optimizes all CSS files *except* for the module or theme being actively developed. This has the benefit of performance (since all files except the actively developed file are compressed) yet allows for quick development.

Which alternative exists for Drupal 7?

Comment: Of course it would be quite easy to upgrade the module and give it a more focused name, if somebody wants to take [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1188540)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, it appears this module is not needed for Drupal 7
this has been committed and fixed in D7 core.

refer to this:

[IE: Stylesheets ignored after 31 link/style tags](http://drupal.org/node/228818)

==========
css aggregation of all stylesheets EXCEPT certain one. just add this to your theme's template file

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/css/custom.css', array(
'group' => CSS_DEFAULT,
'preprocess' => FALSE,
'every_page' => TRUE
));
```

Comment: No, you are missing the point. My question was about css aggregation of all stylesheets EXCEPT certain ones, not about IE compatibility. I have rephrased the question to make it more clear.

Comment: i have edited answer. check your solution.